# Wordpress HTTP API NTLM Authentication

Tags: rest-api, api, authentication, wp-remote-get

I was wondering if anyone has had to use NTLM authentication when using `wp_remote_get`? Trying to authenticate using Basic but that is returning the proxy error. When I use other authenticators for different APIs that do use the Basic method, it works flawlessly!

Anyone got a solution for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has issues like I did, I found this discussion where I added the code and instantly was authenticated. Not sure if its a Wordpress issue or a PHP one, but I feel that the `ANY` portion of the Wordpress authentication was getting blocked first to find the Proxy type, but timing out. Adding the code from this link worked: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31232#comment:7

```
add_action( 'http_api_curl', function( $handle ) {
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
});
```